# Roblox Lua Scripting: OnActivate vs. OnCreate

Tags: roblox

I just started coding in Roblox and I found that there are OnCreate and OnActivate events in their Tool Object. What are the differences between them? It looks like OnCreate is an one-time event when a tool is created while OnActivate when the tool is clicked/used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're spot on! The [Intro to Player Tools](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/intro-to-player-tools) tutorial on the Developer Hub confirms your hunch.